# Force sqoop to re-create hive schemas when importing

Tags: mysql, hadoop, import, hive, sqoop

We are importing databases from MySQL to Hive using Sqoop (1.4.6). Everything works ok, except when table schemas get updated (mainly columns being added) in the source databases. The modifications do not end up in Hive. It seems that the Hive schema is created only once, and not verified in each import. The rows are loaded fine, but of course missing the new columns. We can work around this by first dropping the databases to force a schema re-creation in Hive, but my question is, that is there a way to do this from Sqoop directly?

Our import script resembles:

```
sqoop import-all-tables 
  --compress 
  --compression-codec=snappy 
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://HOST:PORT/DB" 
  --username USER
  --password PASS 
  --hive-import 
  --hive-overwrite 
  --hive-database DB 
  --as-textfile
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use hcatalog table instead of hive, it will work.